# BrainTree Payment issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, braintree

I am using Braintree payment version *3.1.0* . We successfully integrated
into our project ,while doing Payment using credit card
`didSucceedWithPaymentMethod:` is called but we are unable to check-in
transaction in Braintree website (in Transactions summary).

Below is the code I have tried:

```
- (void)informDelegateDidAddPaymentMethod:(BTPaymentMethod *)paymentMethod {

if ([self .delegate
respondsToSelector:@selector(dropInViewController:didSucceedWithPaymentMethod:)])
{

[self.delegate dropInViewController:self

didSucceedWithPaymentMethod:paymentMethod];

}

}

- (void)dropInViewController:(BTDropInViewController *)viewController
didSucceedWithPaymentMethod:(BTPaymentMethod *)paymentMethod {

[viewController.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
completion:nil];

NSMutableArray *newPaymentMethods = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.
paymentMethods];

[newPaymentMethods insertObject:paymentMethod atIndex:0];

self.paymentMethods = newPaymentMethods;

}
```

We are able to get card details in `BTPaymentMethod` but we are unable to
see transaction in braintree website.

How to know whether payment is success or not?

If the payment is not success then is there any delegate method to find
out the error ?

Can you please help me to proceed further.

Comment: are you using sandbox?

Comment: @NullData yes , I am using sandbox

Comment: then check into your sandbox account either payment received or not

Comment: There are no transactions in sandbox account as mentioned in the question already

Comment: What language are you using for your backend integration? Can you include the code where you send `paymentMethod.nonce` to your backend?